# Custom Console Components not showing up?

Tags: sidebar

I have a connected app running and displaying just fine in a page layout, and I would like to show it in the right sidebar.  But I cannot get the right sidebar to show up at all.

For simplicity's sake - I will ignore the connected app.  I've boiled it down to the simplest example I can get - showing a "Related List" on the sidebar.

There's got to be something I'm missing here, but I cannot get Custom Console Components to show up.

This is a Developer account and logging in as System Administrator if that makes a difference.

I went ahead and click on Leads->Edit Layout->Custom Console Components on the Account page.  I went to the Primary tab Components, Right Sidebar, selected Style to be "Stack", width to be 200 px.  For Action, I selected "Related List", checked all the fields available "Contacts, Opportunities....."

I click on the But there is no sidebar showing up.  I've been going through the documentation, and it appears that it should just show up.  Sounds like I'm missing one simple thing.

Comment: Have you added the custom console component to the console app?

Comment: I don't believe so.  How do I go about doing that?

Comment: I just realized I did add the custom console component to the console app.  I went to Setup->User Interface and made sure that "Show Custom Sidebar Components on All Pages" was enabled.

Comment: Perhaps it's collapsed. Can you hover over the panel borders to see if you're able to expand the sidebar?

Comment: @CharlesNaughton your comment above helped me. It was collapsed for me and I was scratching my head all day long why that is not showing up. Thanks